# jQuery .submit() is submitting form in new tab once but not submitting second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form and I have to submit it using jQuery and I am using jQuery v1.12.4. The web application I am working on is using lots of other scripts other than jQuery. Following is my html code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="report-form" method="post">

    <!-- date range picker with start date and end -->
    <div class="input-group date-picker input-daterange" data-date="2012-12-21T15:25:00Z" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" id="from" value="2019-09-30" readonly="">
        <span class="input-group-addon"> to </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" id="to" value="2019-09-30" readonly="">
    </div>

    <!-- first button to submit form for first scenario -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="singleReport" data-type="html">
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- second button to submit form for second scenario -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="singleReport" data-type="pdf">
        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- third button to submit form for third scenario -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="singleReport" data-type="excel">
        <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>
    </a>

</form>
```

I have some other input fields in the form also. Following is my jQuery code to submit form on click of any of the links in above code

```
$(document).on('click','.singleReport', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();

    if(from == '') {
        alert('Select from date!');
    }
    else if(to == '') {
        alert('Select to date!');
    }
    else{
        if($(this).attr('data-type') == 'html')
        {
            $('#report-form').attr('action', '/html');
            $('#report-form').attr('target', '_blank');
            $('#report-form').submit();
        }
        else if($(this).attr('data-type') == 'pdf')
        {
            $('#report-form').attr('action', '/pdf');
            $('#report-form').attr('target', '_blank');
            $('#report-form').submit();
        }
        else if($(this).attr('data-type') == 'excel')
        {
            $('#report-form').attr('action', '/excel');
            $('#report-form').attr('target', '_blank');
            $('#report-form').submit();
        }
    }
});
```

This code successfully submit the form in new tab on first click on any link but it does not submit after that if I click again on the same link or any other link. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your html snippet, so that the issue can be reproduced ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code provided does not, by itself, demonstrate the issue. Please give us some more relevant code and info. Thanks

Comment: @vS12 I have updated the question, kindly check now.

Comment: @ADyson kindly check the question now

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/4u8m67nj/
are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: @Ted yes its working in jsfiddle but its not working in my app and I am not seeing any error in the console. I think the possible reason could be that jQuery could be conflicting with some other script in app. Is it possible?

Comment: " it does not submit after that if I click again on the same link" ...since this code appears to cause a postback, your page would likely be erased and and recreated after the postback (unless this postback causes a file download as the response instead, perhaps?? Or unless you have some different code which intercepts the form submit action and sends it via AJAX instead??). So there wouldn't actually be anything to click on, once the form is submitted. A new page will be returned to the browser.

Comment: Anyway if you have a difference between your environment and the JSFiddle environment, and you have no clues about what's stopping it from functioning, then you may have to resort to trial and error. Strip back your own code down to the absolute basics, create a minimal page containing this functionality, and then build it back up again adding components until it stops working. Then you'll have a better idea of the likely cause. This is the same concept as the creation of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) mentioned in the help page.

Comment: @ADyson no there isn't any file download or any AJAX. You are right, stripping code is what i think i'll have to do to find the problem. Thanks for the help.